# Italian resident moving to Dubai

Tags: taxes, italian-citizens

I am a British citizen, living in Italy, with Italian residency, and married to an Italian. We have three children together. I have been offered a job in Dubai with a two-year contract. Would I need to pay taxes in Italy on my Dubai earnings as my wife and children live in Italy?

Comment: Your question implies that you would go to Dubai alone with your wife and children remaining in Italy; is that in fact what you would do?  Is your Italian residence based on the UK withdrawal agreement or on your being married to an Italian citizen? (I'm not sure it matters, but it might. For example, it might have a bearing on whether you could improve your tax position by relinquishing your Italian residence or on how difficult it would be to reestablish Italian residence when the time comes.)

Comment: I would move, whilst my wife and children would remain in Italy.